# concentration inequalities for quadratic forms of correlated random vectors

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-concentration

Let $\mathbf{n}$ is a Gaussian random vector with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and co-variance matrix $\mathbf{H}$. Let $\mathbf{r} = Sign(\mathbf{n})$, where $Sign(n_i) = 1$ if $n_i>0$ and $Sign(n_i) = -1$ if $n_i<0$. Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a positive semi definite matrix. Let $\sigma = \mathbf{r}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}$. I wanted to know if it is possible to get a concentration inequality for $\sigma$, like

$P(\sigma>E\{\mathbf{n}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{n}\})\leq$ some function, f(N) of the dimensions of vector $\mathbf{r}$.

Any references also would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

We can note that $E\{\mathbf{n}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{n}\} = trace (\mathbf{AH})$, $E\{\mathbf{r}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}\} =\frac{2}{\pi}trace (\mathbf{A}\tilde{\mathbf{H}})$, where $\tilde{\mathbf{H}} = arcSin(\mathbf{H})$, where $arcSin$ (inverse sine) is taken over each entry of $\mathbf{H}$ and $trace(\mathbf{AH})\leq trace(\mathbf{A}\tilde{\mathbf{H}})$ and entries of $\mathbf{H}$ are in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: We, you will have Markov's inequality. Won't that be enough for whatever it is you want to do ?

Comment: @Guillaume Dehaene Using the Markov inequality will give us the trivial bound $P(\sigma>E{\mathbf{n}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{n})\leq 1$, since $\frac{E{\mathbf{r}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}}{E{\mathbf{n}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{n}}\geq 1$

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. So having problems Latexing.

Comment: I see where my mistake is. You're right that markov's bound is trivial in the case you are interested in. That does indicate that any bound you might find will be quite close to 1/2. Is that really an interesting result ?

Comment: @Guillaume Dehaene Yes. Can you please give me a proof or reference.

Comment: Not really. Informally, when n is big enough, $\sigma$ will become close to gaussian from the CLT, and so half of it will be bigger than the mean, and half will be smaller. That's where I was coming from. There are results which bound the mean-median distance, but I'm not too sure if they would apply here

Comment: @ Guillaume Dehaene I am not sure if we can use the CLT since the random variables are not independent. Pl. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Whether we can apply CLT or not in the large n limit depend  on how exactly the H matrix scales when $n$ increases. I can't quite articulate it properly in a comment, but it depends on if the effective rank of H scales *with $n$ or stays constant, or to put it another way, on whether we are really adding degrees of freedom when n increases or if we are just keeping the same number of degrees but streching them out over more dimensions

Comment: In my case H is always full rank. So, in my understanding you propose decorrelating the r vector and using CLT. So I have to look for rate of convergence for the required probability to (1/2).

Comment: Well, you can't decorrelate, because the sign operation is not linear. But consider the following intuition. If H was the identity, the different r would be fully independent and we could apply CLT and get our result. If now H has structure so that the r have mostly local correlation, as long as they are "independent enough", we could still get CLT. However, note that you can get full rank H but with some very high eigenvalues so that the effective rank of H is much lower

Comment: The covariance matrix for the r vector is arcsin(H). I think I was not clear about this earlier. Now, do you think r can be decorrelated? (although the resulting random vector will not be {+1,-1}^N). So I had a doubt if it was ok to still decorrelate!